SwiftUI fileExporter for package documents
While I'm able to use the fileExporter() modifier to export in-memory documents, i.e. single file document (.txt, .jpg, ...) and also for custom file types (after registering them in the project settings with specific UTType), I can't figure out how to use that modifier to export/save a package document.
I have an unified iOS/macOS app tha use a project.json in addition to user selected files.  My custom package document folder looks something like this:
/Users/xyz/somefolder/MyAppFile.myfile
----- project.json
----- file001.mp4
----- file002.jpg
----- file003.mp3
----- etc, etc...

FileDocument protocol asks for Data when saveing, that is correct when you need to export a single file, but not when you need a folder in which you save and copy file during normal App usage.

"FileDocument protocol asks for Data when saving" Can you demonstrate how? FileDocument doesn't do that at all as far as I know. Are you implementing the fileWrapper(configuration:) method? If so, you can simply return a FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: ...).

@Sweeper yes :-) You probably got the problem. I generally implement the fileWrapper(configuration:). Could you show an example in an anwer? It could be the correct one!

In the fileWrapper(configuration:) implementation, create a FileWrapper using init(directoryWithFileWrappers:). This creates a FileWrapper representing a directory.
For example, here is a very bare-bones implementation of FileDocument:
struct MyFile: FileDocument {
    init() {}
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [
            "project.json": FileWrapper(
                regularFileWithContents: """
                    { "some key": "some value" }
                    """.data(using: .utf8)!
            ),
            "foo.txt": FileWrapper(
                regularFileWithContents: """
                    Lorem Ipsum
                    """.data(using: .utf8)!
            ),
        ])
    }
    
    static let readableContentTypes: [UTType] =
    [.init(exportedAs: "your.exported.uttype.identifier", conformingTo: .package)]
    
}

Exporting this will create a package with two files - project.json and foo.txt.
Example usage with .fileExporter:
@State var presented = false
var body: some View {
    Button("Export") {
        presented = true
    }.fileExporter(isPresented: $presented, document: MyFile(), defaultFilename: "Foo") { _ in
        // ...
    }
}


Thanks very much. So I use this wrapper to create the package directory and save project.json each time user saves. And I copy additional files using the classic FileManager copy item method inside that direcotry?

@AltairJones It's a bit hard to talk about this without seeing your actual code. I think what you are describing would work, but why can't you also represent the "additional files" with FileWrapper? Pass the data in those files to FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: ...), or if it is an existing file, use FileWrapper(url: ...).

sorry, I will explain the idea, so if you have any hint that better fit it would be glad if you share with me. Thi is a video editing app. The user creates a project (the package folder containing the .json file). While working with the app the user adds movies and audio clips. So the app, before adding them to the timeline copies those files inside the package to be safely accessed later.

@AltairJones Okay, what I said still stands. Assuming you have the URLs to the audio and video files the user has selected, you'd use FileWrapper(url: ...) to create file wrappers representing the video and audio clips. You can then add those to the package directory using addFileWrapper in a loop. If you have a specific problem regarding this you should probably post a new question.
